# WooCommerce - Create coupon for sale products ONLY

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have searched around the web, but haven't been able to find anything that point me in the right direction.
It is possible to create a coupon in WooCommerce, that doesn't discount sale products, but we need to "reverse it", so it only works with sale products.

Has anyone been able to do that? Any help is appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

How many sale products do you have? Out of the box, you could select the list of products the coupon applies to within its settings

Now that I think of, you could assign all sale products to a given category e.g. "Sale items", and use that to include product categories in the coupon settings

Otherwise, if you don't want to to things manually, there is some PHP to write